# Creating social website in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

I'm creating a social Networking Website for that I used "Social Networking Website in ASP.NET - Open Source" from
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/social-networking-website-in-Asp-Net-open-source-project/
When I tried to run the project on my Visual Studio 2012 edition it is showing error like below,

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
Source Error:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


/// <summary>
/// Summary description for DataBaseClass
/// </summary>
public class DataBaseClass
{
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    public DataBaseClass()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public void ConnectDataBaseToInsert(string Query)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Veena-SQLServer2008; Initial Catalog=RNetworkingWebApplication;");
        cmd.CommandText = Query;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);        
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();       
        con.Close();

    }
    public DataSet ConnectDataBaseReturnDS(string Query)
    {
        ds = new DataSet();
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Veena-SQLServer2008; Initial Catalog=RNetworkingWebApplication;");
        cmd.CommandText = Query;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();        
        return ds;
    }
    public DataTable ConnectDataBaseReturnDT(string Query)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Veena-SQLServer2008; Initial Catalog=RNetworkingWebApplication;");
        cmd.CommandText = Query;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Visual studio pointing the error here da.Fill(dt).
I have spent 2 days to debug this error but still I couldn't. Please help me.

Comment: Anytime you are dealing with connection strings, you should [consult connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

Comment: Oh my. The title indicates a project, and the question is trivial. Graulations for that - maybe you should cut the blablabla and hav a title AND question that are as little as possible. NOTHING in your code has anything to do with ASP.NET and nothing has anything to do with a social website.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. Your code is not able to connect to the database. Open Server Explorer in Visual Studio and connect to your database to confirm you are able to connect. And then get your connection string right.

And you do have a database, right?

Comment: Thank you sir. I have tried that also when I'm trying to connect the same error message is coming like The attempt to attach to the database failed with the following information, A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) Source Error:

Comment: Can you connect to your sql server database through Sql Server Management Studio? If not, your sql server instance might not be turned on.

Comment: Yeah,I can connect. The visual studio is only not allowing to connect any database. Help me.

Comment: Are you using Sql login or windows?

Comment: I have the database in my server explorer. I copied the connection string then changed the connection string. I couldn't understand when I'm using open source what are things I want to change to run that project in my machine please explain clearly.

Comment: The dbml or entity might have a default connection string.

Comment: Do I want to keep that as it is?

Comment: Thank you  for your help. Now it is working after restarting services